# Does np.random.poisson work with very small numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, poisson

I'm trying to simulate a system of reactions over time. In order to do this I have to multiply the value of probability of a reaction occurring with a pre-calculated time step that it can occur in, save this result in new variable and use the new variable to sample from the poisson distribution.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
lam = (evaluate_propensity*delta_t)    
rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam) # probability of a reaction firing in the given time period
```

I've written a function to calculate the value of delta_t based on system specific parameters, the value calculated is very small `0.00014970194372884217` and I think this is having an impact on the np.random.poisson function.

The `evaluate_propensity` variable is an array that details the probability of a reaction occurring based on the number of molecules in the system and the ratios between molecules in a reaction. This is calculated dynamically and changes after each iteration as the molecule numbers change, but the values for the first iteration are:

```
evaluate_propensity = np.array([1.0, 0.002, 0.0, 0.0])
```

The documentation states that `lam` must be `>= 0` and mine is (just) but `rxn_vector` just always returns an array of zeros.

```
rxn_vector = [0 0 0 0]
```

I know that the last two elements of the array will evaluate to zero. But didn't think that the first two would as well. Is there a way to make it more sensitive or amplify my results somehow or am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "always returns zero"? How many samples did you take? lambda = 1.5e-4 is very tiny.

Comment: I've drawn 4 samples one for each reaction (I think)

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability to draw a non-zero number for `lambda = 1.5e-4` is tiny, it is `P(k>0) = 1 - P(k=0) = 1.5e-4`. On average you'd have to draw a lot more than four samples to get a non-zero value, `1 / 1.5e-4 = 6667` samples for `propensity = 1`. For smaller values the number of necessary samples is obviously even larger.

You can confirm this with `scipy.stats`

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

pdist = poisson(1.5e-4)
prob = 1 - pdist.pmf(0)
print(prob) # 0.00014998875056249084
```